# Functions not firing in correct order with async / await

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

In an Angular service, I have created the following function:

```
getListKey(user) {
  firebase.database().ref(`userprofile/${user.uid}/list`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    this.listKey = snapshot.val()
    return this.listKey
  })
}
```

I want to call this function in another file on load, and assign the value brought back to a global `listKey` variable in the service to be used for another function from the component. However, the second function is firing before the data has been retrieved even with using `async`/`await`.

This is the relevant piece from my component:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async (user: firebase.User) => {
  await this.fire.getListKey(user);
  this.fire.getUserList(this.fire.listKey).subscribe(lists => {...})
  ...
}
```

How can I make `getUserList()` wait for `listKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a return statement to getListKey to return the promise. Otherwise, you're returning undefined, and awaiting undefined will not wait for the database snapshot to be ready.

```
getListKey(user) {
  return firebase.database().ref(`userprofile/${user.uid}/list`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    this.listKey = snapshot.val()
    return this.listKey
  })
}
```

Also, you probably want a left side to your await:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async (user: firebase.User) => {
  const listKey = await this.fire.getListKey(user);
  this.fire.getUserList(listKey).subscribe(lists => {...})
  ...
}
```